# Amazon ECS: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have a Fargate app running in AWS ECS, which I'm trying to update by the AWS CLI (aws-cli/1.16.96 Python/2.7.15 Darwin/18.0.0 botocore/1.12.86 ).

I've built and pushed the image successfully, and created a new task definition version.

When I'm trying to update the service with the following commands :

```
aws ecs update-service 
    --cluster cluster-winquest-qa 
    --service container-qa-ge-service 
    --desired-count 0
```

```
aws ecs update-service 
    --cluster cluster-qa 
    --service container-service 
    --task-definition first-run-task-definition:5 
    --platform-version "LATEST"  
    --desired-count 1
```

Throws the following error message :

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE
```

Then I tried to add  --launch-type "FARGATE" to the command above mentioned, building the following command :

```
aws ecs update-service 
    --cluster cluster-qa 
    --service container-service 
    --task-definition first-run-task-definition:5 
    --platform-version "LATEST" 
    --launch-type "FARGATE"  
    --desired-count 1
```

It throws :
`Unknown options: --launch-type, FARGATE`

I know that the error mesage said that the task definition is not supported for Fargate apps, but I want to know how can I update the service to the lastest task definition version using AWS CLI. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was how I was creating the new version of the task definition, there I had to configure `requiresCompatibilities` param to specify it.

I used this doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate.html

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue while setting up an Amazon ECS cluster using Terraform.

All you need to do is to add this attribute below to your `aws_ecs_task_definition` block:

```
requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
```

So your task definition file will look somehow like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "aetd" {
  family                   = var.family
  network_mode             = var.network_mode
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.cpu
  memory                   = var.memory
  execution_role_arn       = var.execution_role_arn
  task_role_arn            = var.task_role_arn
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at ecs command line reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html) `update-service` does not support `--launch-type` flag. The reason it does not support this flag is because you are trying to update a service which is already created. You can only specify launch type when you are running `create-service` ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html)).

The reason you might be getting the first error is because you did not create the cluster using **Powered by AWS Fargate** cluster type. You are using `--platform-version` flag which is only used for Fargate type of clusters (mentioned in AWS documentation).

Also, to let your service use the latest task definition you can simply *not* use the `--task-definition` flag because by default if a revision is not specified it uses the latest ACTIVE revision.